# Reinstall SQL server in windows server 2012?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql

I have SharePoint server.

I did mistake to uninstall SQL server so now SharePoint site is also not opening.

so please some one help me how can I reinstall SQL so my existing SharePoint site works as before?

Comment: Hi hardik, I was uninstalled sharepoint server and again i installed but old site template was not deleting from sharepoint central admin

Comment: How i can remove the site template from central admin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer for the question is **simply NO**. Your `SharePoint Server` is no more live.

As you have already mentioned in the question that you have uninstalled the `SQL server` from `Windows Server 2012`, then all databases deleted from the server.

As we all know that, `SharePoint` works on `SQL server` database as **it's a back-end**. So in your case `SharePoint` is **defiantly not going to work**.

You can reinstall the SQL server but you cannot get all the databases back which are created by SharePoint.

Although you get back all the databases within the `SQL server` than you need to reconnect the `SharePoint` server to `SQL database` called `Config`

So I think that you have already lost all entire `SharePoint` by uninstalling the `SQL server`

Comment: using web platform installer now i was installing sql server so after installation it was working or not ?

Comment: otherwise what shall i do again i need to install SharePoint server ?

Comment: Yes you need to install SharePoint server again. Feeling sad for you... :(

Comment: after sql server installation also the site is not opening ?

Comment: No it will not work as your connection between SP & SQL is already lost

Comment: Ohh..... for this situation there is no option ....?

Comment: You must have to reinstall entire SharePoint from scratch dear...

Comment: for this sql server uninstall visual studio also affect ?
in my visual studio asp.net web apllication,mvc application template not there ?

Comment: i need to reinstall visual studio also..?

Comment: hai hardik please reply me i need to reinstall visual studio also ?

Comment: No you do not need to reinstall VS.. As SharePoint is not dependent on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39499/discussion-between-hardik-and-kavitha).